# sql where the numbers in the string equals to keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I want to search question no. which can be 1, 1a, 1b, 2, 2c, 11. How can I to search 1 getting 1, 1a, 1b but not 11. And if I search 1b, only 1b comes out.
Is there any function helps?

using mysql

```
DATA:
id    |question   |q_no.
1     |XX         |1
2     |ABC        |1a
3     |ED         |1c
1     |CD         |11

Desired sets:
when searching "1":
1     |XX         |1
2     |ABC        |1a
3     |ED         |1c

when searching "1a":
2     |ABC        |1a
```

sorry for being late

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered.  Try: (1) including sample data; (2) desired results; (3) code that you have written; (4) tag the question with the database you are using.  Also, a SQL Fiddle can help.

Comment: Make a function do_sql which takes the first argument for a `LIKE` where clause in the sql command the function will create. Than call the function with the desired parameters: `do_sql "1b"``. Or explain what you really want and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help. It run in mysql.

```
SELECT---
FROM---
WHERE question_no REGEXP '1[^1]'
```

It will show question_no start with character '1' and followed by except character '1'

Answer (score 1):

I think `regexp` is your best approach:

```
where question_no regexp concat('^', $SearchQ, '[^0-9]')
```